# SimpleForm not Submitting

Tags: html, simple-form

I am a new user to simpleform (and html in general), and I am having trouble setting up a contact form for my jekyll website. This is the source I am using for my contact page. The email box seems to check for inconsistent input when submitted, but I don't get redirected or get any output.

Thanks in Advance!

```html
<section id="contact">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading">Contact</h2>
            <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Thanks for Contacting Me!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <form action="http://getsimpleform.com/messages?form_api_token=2d6935f301203a8a2b595dfa0141a48a" method="post">
            <!-- the redirect_to is optional, the form will redirect to the referrer on submission -->
            <input type='hidden' name='redirect_to' value='http://www.google.com' />
            <!-- all your input fields here.... -->
            Name:<input type='text' name='name'/></br>
            Email:<input type='email' name='email'/></br>
            Message:<textarea name='message'></textarea>
            <button type='submit' value='Submit Form'>Submit:</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This form works. After submitting, I'm directed to google.com as this is how the form is set up. If you provide the URL to your live site, I'll have a look.

Comment: I've already moved to a different solution, so I pulled down what was on the live site already. I still can't seem to get it to redirect though... Does it matter what browser/extensions I am using? I am also hosting via github, would that pose a problem?

Comment: You might want to update your question with your new problem. I'll take a look then.